# Calculate number of values in vector that exceed values in column of data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a long list of numbers, e.g.

```
 set.seed(123)
 y<-round(runif(100, 0, 200))
```

And I would like to store in column `y` the number of values that exceed each value in column `x` of a data frame:

```
 df <- data.frame(x=seq(0,200,20))
```

I can compute the numbers manually, like this:

```
length(which(y>=20)) #93 values exceed 20
length(which(y>=40)) #81 values exceed 40
```

etc. I know I can use a for-loop with all values of x, but is there a more elegant way?

I tried this:

```
 df$y <- length(which(y>=df$x))
```

But this gives a warning and does not give me the desired output.

The data frame should look like this:

```
df
     x   y
1  0 100
2  20  93
3  40  81
4  60  70
5  80  61
6  100  47
7  120  40
8  140  29
9  160  19
10 180   8
11 200   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare each value of `df$x` against all value of `y` using `sapply`

```
sapply(df$x, function(a) sum(y>a))
#[1] 99 93 81 70 61 47 40 29 18  6  0

#Looking at your output, maybe you want
sapply(df$x, function(a) sum(y>=a))
#[1] 100  93  81  70  61  47  40  29  19   8   0
```

Here's another approach using `outer` that allows for element wise comparison of two vectors

```
rowSums(outer(df$x,y, "<="))
#[1] 100  93  81  70  61  47  40  29  19   8   0
```

Yet one more (from alexis_laz's comment)

```
length(y) - findInterval(df$x, sort(y), left.open = TRUE)
# [1] 100  93  81  70  61  47  40  29  19   8   0
```

Comment: As another idea, to avoid the all-with-all comparisons and many summations, `findInterval` is handy for such tasks -- `length(y) - findInterval(df$x, sort(y), left.open = TRUE)`